# Force Exchange -> Outlook ContactItem sync

Tags: synchronization, vsto, exchangewebservices, contactitem

Does anyone know if there is there a way, preferably using EWS on the Exchange server or VSTO c# code in an Add-In for the Outlook client, to programmatically force an immediate sync of a given ContactItem that was updated on the Exchange Server to the Outlook Client? Or to force a general sync of ContactItems?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can't force a sync from EWS you need to use VSTO to initiate a Send/Receive, UpdateFolder etc I would suggest taking a look at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cf971fca-466f-4ef8-aceb-8660649dd4e5/c-outlook-inbox-not-refreshing-with-latest-messages?forum=vsto